# Assigned the .conf file type to always open with Adobe Illustrator. How to revert back?

Tags: windows-10, file-association, adobe-illustrator

I am using Windows 10 and I accidentally made Adobe Illustrator the default program to open .conf files. I believe this is messing with my other programs and need to revert this back to whatever it was by default.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **Control Panel** -> **Programs** -> **Default Programs** -> **Set Default Programs**.
2. You will be presented with the list of all installed programs. Choose Adobe Illustrator.
3. In the bottom-right, select the option "Choose defaults for this program"
4. You will be presented with a list of files - unselect .conf file type.